# XSL Choose not working

Tags: xml, xslt

Choose statement goes as positive on test="./Category" even if /Category is empty.

The value of Category values is < ![CDATA[]] > if empty and < ![CDATA[some_code]] > if full.

It seems like CDATA leaves "" to the value or something like that.

```
     <xsl:when test="./Category">
             <ref type="category"><xsl:value-of select="./Category" /></ref>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <id_category_default>2</id_category_default>
     </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test `test="./Category"` is simply testing for the existing of an element named `Category` in your XML, and does not take into an child nodes of that element.

The test you want is probably this (Note that `./` is not necessary here)

```
<xsl:when test="Category[normalize-space()]">
```

This will ignore text consisting of nothing but white-space. If you consider the presence white-space to be "non-empty", try this instead...

```
<xsl:when test="Category[. != '']">
```